# How to select child elements after using groupSVGElements

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am loading an svg into Fabric which has child elements. I'm grouping them using groupSVGElements().

I need to be able select each child element - that is an onclick event that allows me to select a child object.

I've thrown together this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AnQW5/2/

Although I can list out the child objects of the group via getObjects, theres no way that I can see to determine which object was clicked. So :

```
    canvas.observe('object:selected', function(e) {
       console.log(e.target.getObjects());
       // ???
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting and a tough nut to crack—no luck so far.  Both canvas.containsPoint() and canvas.findTarget() don’t work on objects contained in a PathGroup.   The ungroup+hittest+regroup trick doesn’t work with PathGroup—no remove().  Loading the SVG into a regular Group doesn’t work because the svg defined positions aren’t always retained.  Do you just need to do only translate transforms?  If so, the next attempt might be to break your svg into ungrouped elements and then transform each with a single “group” transformation matrix.

Comment: Yup, that was my next move. But I was hoping that I could use groupSVGElements and position the group on the canvas with just one set of x,y coords.

Comment: I want to do same thing but I don't have any idea to do that I have found this on http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ but svg is loading in group and if I select ungroup then we cannot select the objects please if an one get answer post here Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a reviver function thats a parameter of loadSVGFromString and loadSVGFromURL. I used this to iterate over each svg child object and add them to a fabric.group.  Then to determine which object was clicked on the canvas, I used this http://jsfiddle.net/LNt2g/6/ (ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196603/using-containspoint-to-select-object-in-group); This basically loops over each object on the canvas and if its a group, loops over the children.

Comment: I want to load svg without grouping on the canvas. so that I can select child elements of the svg. in the example given in the  fabricjs.com/kitchensink working fine but the bounding boxes for each elements are not proper

Comment: Any progress on this? I am facing the same situation where I load an svg using loadSVGFromURL and then group it with groupSVGElements to change the group's position, but after that it would be great just to ungroup it to have direct access to the child elements. I tried a couple of things but still no luck. Have you guys had any luck?

Answer (score 4):

You can use 
canvas.add.apply instead groupSVGElements, so you can : 
have each element to manipulate

```js
var shapesSvg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="320" height="240" viewBox="0 0 320 240"><rect id="rect" x="5" y="50" width="100" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255,0,0);"></rect> <circle id="circle" cx="165" cy="100" r="50" style="fill: rgb(0,255,0);"/></svg>';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setHeight($(window).height());
canvas.setWidth($(window).width());


fabric.loadSVGFromString(shapesSvg, function(objects, options) {
  canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Description

The following code detects any object on the screen by it's color, not the best thought.

### Code

```
var $canvas = {
    activePaths: []
};

// Bind to `onMouseDown` event.
function onMouseDown = function (options) {

    var mousePos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
    mousePos.x = parseInt(mousePos.x);
    mousePos.y = parseInt(mousePos.y);

    var width =  canvas.getWidth();
    var height = canvas.getHeight();

    var pixels = canvas.getContext().getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var pixel = (mousePos.x + mousePos.y * pixels.width) * 4;

    var activePathsColor = new fabric['Color']('rgb(' + pixels.data[pixel] + ',' + pixels.data[pixel + 1] + ',' + pixels.data[pixel + 2] + ')');
    var colorHex = '#' + activePathsColor.toHex().toLowerCase();

    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var activePath = [];

    // Check if active objects are type of `group`, if so push the selected path.
    if(activeObject.type == 'group') {

          for (var i = 0; i < activeObject.getObjects().length; i++) {
            var path = activeObject.getObjects()[i];
            if (path.getFill().toLowerCase() == colorHex) {
                $canvas.activePaths.push(path);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

### References

Events: http://fabricjs.com/events/